# Monodroid platform

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm new on Monodroid platform, I wonder is there good references/books/examples that integrate Monodroid with Google javascript API (Drive, Calendar, Contact, etc.). What I know is that there Client Library for .NET/C# but I fail integrate it with Monodroid (not understand to use OAuth on Monodroid too)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a collection of links which you might find helpful:

- Mono for Android docs home: http://docs.xamarin.com/android
- MfA samples: http://samples.xamarin.com/Android
- MfA recipes: http://docs.xamarin.com/android/Recipes

Answer (score 2):

Lots of samples at https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples from Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

I've always found Wally's books rock solid for instruction.  He and a few others authored "Android Programming with Mono for Android and .NET/C#" published by Wrox.  Search amazon, there are other books out there too.

There is a 3 book set also published by Wrox; the 3-pack includes a book on iOS development using C# (MonoTouch) and a book identifying some cross-platform techniques and patterns for tying the codebases together.

The book titles are:

- Professional Cross-Platform Mobile Development in C#
- Professional iPhone Programming with MonoTouch and .NET/C#
- Android Programming with Mono for Android and .NET/C#